# What's the most pythonic way to check to what particular range (out of many) a number belongs?

Tags: python, if-statement, range

I know I can check if a number X belongs to a particular range (out of Y consecutive ranges) by using concatenated `if a<X<b elif b<X<C else ...`but is there a more concise, pythonic way to do so?

Comment: @Austin modified to make it even more explicit

Comment: Do you want the same action in each case (`if a < X < b or b < X < C or ...`) or a different action in each case?

Comment: Is `X` always an integer? What about `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.?

Comment: What is a *`pythonic range`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several way, this one seems not so bad :

```py
def in_range(number : int, arange : range) -> bool:
    return number in arange

ranges = [range(6), range(4, 14), range(10, 20), range(12, 34)]
results = list(filter(lambda arange : in_range(5, arange), ranges))
print(results)
```

> [range(0, 6), range(4, 14)]

You can simplify it like this.

```py
def in_range(number : int, ranges : List[range]) -> List[range]:
    return [arange for arange in ranges if number in arange]

ranges = [range(6), range(4, 14), range(10, 20), range(12, 34)]
print(in_range(6, ranges))
```

> [range(0, 6), range(4, 14)]

You may want to know it on the fly.

```py
def in_range(number : int, start : int, stop : int) -> bool:
    return number in range(start,stop)
```

### Edit 1

You can also used `any` or want to test it for float, in this case look at **@chepner** comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `any`:

```
x = 57
ranges = [range(10), range(15,27), range(38,42), range(49, 63), range(70, 95)]
if any(x in range for range in ranges):
    ...
```

If you can't use `range` (because you are testing against an interval with non-integer end points), store the interval as a tuple.

```
ranges = [(1.5, 3.7), ...]
if any(t1 < x < t2 for t1, t2 in ranges):
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question? It seems to me what OP want to know *which* of the ranges `x` belongs to, not just whether it's in any of them or not.

Comment: Possibly not; I asked the OP to clarify the question after posting this.

Answer (score 1):

If your consecutive ranges are dense (meaning there are no gaps in between), I would do

```
def get_range(boundaries, x):
    for a, b in zip(boundaries, boundaries[1:]):
        if a < x < b:
            return a, b

# Test example
boundaries = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
x = 13
a, b = get_range(boundaries, x)
print(a, b)  # 10 15
```

Note that the exact boundaries are not included in any of the ranges! I.e. `get_range(boundaries, 10)` does not find any range. To fix this, replace `a < x < b` with e.g. `a <= x < b`.

The above is great if you have a lot of ranges, where a hard-coded `if`-`elif` chain would be impractical. That said, if you have millions of ranges, you might want to be a bit more clever, like implementing a binary search.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to implement the equivalent of a switch statement (there isn't one in Python), you could define a utility function to make the code more concise and readable (i.e. avoiding repetitions):

```
def switch(value):
    def inRange(a,b): 
        return a <= value and value < b
    return inRange

number = 25

case = switch(number)
if   case(10,20): print("small")
elif case(20,50): print("medium")
elif case(50,90): print("large")
else:             print("huge")
```

you could also use this with ternary operators:

```
inRange = switch(number)
size    = "small"  if inRange(10,20) else \
          "medium" if inRange(20,50) else \
          "large"  if inRange(50,90) else \
          "huge"

print(size)
```

If your ranges are consecutive, you could avoid repeating the upper boundaries using a bisecting search (which would give better performance for large lists of ranges):

```
ranges = [10,20,50,90]
sizes  = ["small","medium","large","huge"]
from bisect import bisect_right
size = sizes[bisect_right(ranges,number)-1]
print(size)
```